# Which software can shift voice formant?

Tags: linux, python, audio, voice

Melodyne does exactly what I need but it is UI only. I'm looking for a way to shift formant of the voice programmatically. ffmpeg, sox, praat..? How can I do this?

In speech science and phonetics, a [formant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant) (phonetics term) is the spectral shaping that results from an acoustic resonance of the human vocal tract.

**What kind of application are you looking for?**
Command line or python package.

**What operating system do you want the application to run on?**
Linux

**What budget do you have?**
0

**What features must the application have?**
The ability to change voice formant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [python](https://www.python.org/) library [praatio](https://pypi.org/project/praatio/) which makes extensive use of [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) includes the capability to raise/lower all speech formants by a fixed percentage amongst other possible manipulations. The documentation can be found at http://timmahrt.github.io/praatIO/ and some examples in a Jupter Notebook [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/timmahrt/praatIO/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial1_intro_to_praatio.ipynb).

- Python, praatio & Praat are free, gratis & Open Source
- All of the above runs on multiple platforms
- There is considerable additional capability
- Various licences apply (PSF, GPL & MIT)